# SIGSEGV segmentation fault when deleting a node from a linked list

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I'm trying to delete the first occurence of a value from a singly linked list. However this generates a segmentation fault whenever it's called.

```
typedef struct Node *node;
struct Node
{
    int data;
    node next;
};

node delete_node(int value, node l) {
    if (l == NULL){
      return NULL;
    }
    if (l->data == value) {
      node temp;
      temp = l->next;
      free(l);
      return temp;
    }
    l->next = delete_node(value, l->next);
    return l;
}
```

Comment: This shouldn't even compile (you are missing a semicolon).

Comment: Please add the part related to the creation of the list and the code of this calling part.

Comment: You're confusing value and data, right ?

Answer (score 0):

See the name of this site.
This code may cause stack overflow.
when the linked list is long.

p.s.

> ```
> if (l->_value_ == value) {
> ```

might be l->*data*?